# Reading JSON from pages incrementally

Tags: java, json, api, rest, httprequest

I have a java client that reads JSON from a web service. The first part of thejson response (offset 1 - 20) is of the format below. I can currently parse the first page of the data into a file (though i will love to parse into  db eventually). How can I get the client to parse the next page (offset 21 - 40) ? The second part of the file has more information intentionally omitted for brevity sake. I have used the apache http client but it seems there is no method to handle this ? Will be grateful if pointed to the right directoin.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 15,
        "next": "/abc/api/defapi/lkk/?username=abc&api_key=xyz&limit=15&offset=60&format=json",
        "offset": 30,
        "previous": "/abc/api/defapi/lkk/?username=abc&api_key=xyz&limit=15&offset=30&format=json",
        "total_count": 312213
      },

  "objects": [
    {
      "availability": "COMPLETE",
      "confidentiality": "",
      "cpe_id": [
        {
          "name": "cpe:/o:sun:sunos:5.11::express"
        }
NOTE:truncated for brevity
```

Comment: that's not json. it's missing a `"` on the `previous` value, which means it's syntactically incorrect and therefore invalid.

Comment: @MarcB ...that was my mistake, sorry. I copied it wrongly, I think is a valid json response. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Still not valid json, the `"meta":` in front of the first `{` should not be there.

Comment: @Henry.. i have edited the json accordingly, "meta" is part of the json . Many thanks.

Comment: grab the "next" url and make another http call.  repeat until there is no "next" url.

Comment: @Henry can you expatiate a little on how to do that, still a newbie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks all the answers and pointers to my question. The code below does what I wanted i.e. grabs json files and save on disk, incrementally. I think it is still very basic hence I would appreciate all criticisms on better approaches, coding styles. Still learning !!

```
        while (count < totalCount ) {
                MyClient check = new MyClient();
                check.checkSecurity();

                System.out.println(" ************ Starting with count " + count + " ***********************");
                URI uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url)
               .addParameter("limit", String.valueOf(limit))
               .addParameter("offset", String.valueOf(offset))
                .build();   

                System.out.println("The URL built is --> " + uriBuilder); 
                HttpGet hget = new HttpGet(uriBuilder);
                System.out.println(hget.getRequestLine());

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
                hget.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");             

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(hget);                                       
                    URL vdbUrl = uriBuilder.toURL();
                    System.out.println("Response status : " + response.getStatusLine());
                    HttpEntity entity2 = response.getEntity();

                    do {
                        vdbInput = new File("C:/myfiles/entry_0" + filenamePostfix + ".json");
                        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(vdbUrl, vdbInput);        
                        System.out.println("File successfully written from page " +  count );
                        System.out.println("page is : "  + vdbUrl);
                        filenamePostfix++;                                                  
                        count++;
                        offset = offset + 20;

                    } while (filenamePostfix < count) ;

                    EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
                }
        }
```